# Linux - Syslog client

Tags: linux, client, udp, syslog, rsyslog

In order to develop a cross-plateform syslog client, I am trying to do it without using the syslog syscall. I am developping this client in C++ and for now testing in `Linux`. The old syslog client that I am replacing was working perfectly fine with the syslog syscall.
For how, it simply doesn't work. The trace is not in `/var/log/user.log` like it should be, either anywhere else (`grep`ed). But I do receive it when I listen on the right port with `netcat`. Shouldn't the port `514` be already in use by the way ?

The trace is as it should be sent on `UDP/514`. I tried to stick the RFC 3164 but something is still obviously wrong.

Id really appreciate if someone could give me a hint to solve this.

```
Trace: severity: 2 (Critical); facility: 23 (Local Use 7) ==> priority: 186

sh$> sudo nc -ul localhost -p 514
  <186>Oct 18 10:36:03 hostname test_trace: | 10:36:03.242995 | CRIT  | xxx-MAIN[5473-000] | 00000 | 0008 : main : user_msg
```

Thank you !

---

I think I found the problem in my own question: Rsyslog (my syslog server) doesn't listen on UDP/514 correctly.

/etc/rsyslog.conf

```
$ModLoad imudp
$UDPServerAddress 0.0.0.0
$UDPServerRun 514
```

If someone has any idea of why it still doesn't listen on UDP/514, I'd be really thanksful cause I really don't see why.

Thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syslog() call writes to /dev/log and the system logger reads this unix domain socket to pick up the message. UDP/514 is for network transmission.
So it is not clear what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You are right. Well, I think I simply mis-configured my syslog server to work with remote clients. I need to make it listen on UDP/514 cause it's not its default behavior apparently.